# javascript, float and display not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a pretty simple javascript menu with a click function to slideUp and Down.
The javascript code seems to be working but something is messing with the css.

I've tried a couple of things but can't get it to work.

Here's the demo:
http://goo.gl/BoIwm

I appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks!

Comment: Your menu show hide works fine. float and display are working and that's the problem. You need to set position or change in your HTML markup for re-structuring the menu.

Comment: Right. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GX3BA/)

Comment: timidboy, I just copied your changes into my code but it still not working...

Comment: my bad, it's working I just cleaned my cache! :) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/L6cMC/1/)

I have rearranged the subitems div so that the position of them appearing below the respective menu item..  Otherwise you need to specify the exact postion if you are placing them outside the wrapper..

You code seems to be right ,but the position was messing it up..

I have removed the javascript function and specified the click event for the anchor tag..

Comment: I just did the timidboy changes and it worked! 
I've tried your solution and it worked too!

Answer (score 0):

Your code,

Try below function. It should work. Also make a fiddle and update your question with all styles. that way i can suggest a better/single function

```
$(".Índice").click(function() {
    $(".subindice").slideDown();
});

$(".caeplus").click(function() {
    $(".subcae").slideDown();
});

$(".Follow").click(function() {
    $(".subfollow").slideDown();
});
```